# How to stop all traffic on metered network

Tags: ufw

I want to put a Raspberry Pi computer running Ubuntu Server 22.04 with a cellular modem in a weather station on a mountain, and my data plan is metered. I only want to be charged for data relevant to the weather station.

In testing, I've set UFW to deny all incoming traffic, deny all outgoing traffic, routing is disabled, and I still see a little chatter coming and going I can't explain.

I'm assuming any pinging between the cell tower and the modem is not showing up in the System Monitor > Resources > Network tab since the cellular modem radio is external to my host computer running Ubuntu.

What could this extra chatter be and can it be stopped without disconnecting the modem? I'm trying to keep down long term expenses.

Thank you, Kevin